# Interfere in Jersey REST life cycle

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have variant resources that all extend `BaseResource<T>`

```
@Component
@Path("/businesses")
public class BusinessResource extends BaseResource<Business>{

   @GET
   @Path({businessId}/)
   public Business getBusiness(@PathParam("businessId") Integer businessId){..}
}

@Component
@Path("/clients")
public class ClientResource extends BaseResource<Client>{

   @GET
   @Path({clientId}/)
   public Client getClient(@PathParam("clientId") Integer clientId){..}
}
```

I would like, that when there is a call to 
`/businesses/3`, it will first go through a method that I will write which validates the `T` object and if everything is ok I will tell jersey to continue handling the resource.
Same goes for Client.

I can't use a regular servlet/filter - since it's being called BEFORE jersey servlet and I wouldn't know which resource is being called.

What is the best way to do it in Jersey?

Is there a place to **interfere between knowing the method that jersey will invoke and the invokation?**

Comment: Aspect oriented programming. AspectJ.

Comment: Can you please give an example how to use it in jersey?

Comment: Maybe: http://www.javakaffee.de/blog/2008/11/15/how-to-use-spring-aop-in-jersey-added-example-resource-class-to-the-spring-annotations-sample/

Comment: This will require the other programmers to use Secure annotation above each method. I would like it to be above the class name, but if it's above the class - how would I get the @PathParam businessId or userId to validate?

Comment: That was just an example. You don't have to use it with annotations. Read up on aspects. You can have access to the method parameters.

Comment: why not a DAO that is utilized from getBusiness()?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I read about AspectJ. The question is how do I extract the request info? or in another question, how do I pass it to the class SecurityAdvice in the example?

Comment: @SatelliteSD how would I call this method in infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 basic http methods in REST, namly `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`.
Your annotation tells Jersey what method to call when a `http request` occurs. Jersey looks up the target `URI` in the request and matches it against your model. If the request is a `http get` it will execute the method annotiated with `@Get` from the class with the correct `@Path` annotiaton.
Usually you dont want to grant access to your resources in this annotated method directly. A common (may not perfect) way is to implement a `DAO` class that handles access to your resources, and of course does the validation before it returns the resource back to the `@Get` annotated method, which will itself only pass the resource to the client. So you will get another layer in your application between persisting (SQL, etc) and the client interface (Jersey).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jersey 2.x ContainerRequestFilters with NameBinding. After having matched the resource, the bound filter will be executed prior to executing the method itself.
You can see the Jersey user guide, which states that it is possible:
[Chapter 9.2.1.1](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8148)  explains about PreMatching and PostMatching filters and [chapter 9.4](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8397) chapter shows the execution order of jersey filters.

See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556961/intercept-jax-rs-request-register-a-containerrequestfilter-with-tomcat) for the implementation where I had the problem to make the filters with jersey 2 work.