# Intercept JAX-RS Request: Register a ContainerRequestFilter with tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I am trying to intercept a request to my JAX-RS webservice by a ContainerRequestFilter. I want to use it with a custom annotation, so I can decorate certain methods of the webservice. This should enable me to handle requests to this methods based on the information whether they are made on a secure channel
or not, before the actual method is executed.

I tried different approaches, searched several posts and then implemented mostly based on the answer by Alden in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785001/custom-method-annotation-using-jerseys-abstracthttpcontextinjectable-not-workin/20611842#20611842).
But I can't get it working.

I have a method test in my webservice decorated with my custom annotation Ssl.

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Ssl
public static Response test(){      
    System.out.println("TEST ...");
}
```

The annotation looks like this:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Ssl {}
```

Then I setup a filter implementation

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Ssl
@Provider
public class SslInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {       
        System.out.println("Filter executed.");
    }
}
```

But the filter is never executed nor there occur any error messages or warnings. The test method runs fine anyway.

To resolve it, I tried to register the filter in the web.xml as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300218/jersey-containerrequestfilter-not-triggered).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.my.packagewithfilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.packagewithfilter.SslInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>  
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
      <param-value>com.my.packagewithfilter</param-value>
    </init-param>    

  </servlet>
```

But that also doesn't work. What am I missing? Any ideas how to make that filter work? Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using JAX-RS 2.0 APIs (request filters, name binding, ...) in your classes but Jersey 1 proprietary init params in your `web.xml` (package starting with `com.sun.jersey`, Jersey 2 uses `org.glassfish.jersey`). Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086218/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletco/18099938#18099938) and at these articles:

- [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/)
- [Binding JAX-RS Providers to Resource Methods](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/08/binding-jax-rs-providers-to-resource-methods/)

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I am aware, I wasn't sure which classes to reference in the web.xml. Actually, I got the filter working using com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter instead of
javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter. But than its just global and so its useless for my case. I guess that NameBinding for the method doesn't work because I use jersey 1.x. But trying to switch to jersey 2.x put me to major troubles with the project
startup in tomcat. Maybe I should try that again and hope it resolves the issues.

Comment: Now I created a new clean JAX-RS project only based on Jersey 2. Now I can use javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter and bind it to certain methods of my services. works perfectly now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Just compiling the answer from Michael Gajdos to help someone who do not want open more tabs:

When you are using Jersey-2 you must use the follow configuration to register your filter into the web.xml

**jersey.config.server.provider.classnames**

instead of

**com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters** (jersey-1x)

```
 <!-- This is the config needed -->
<servlet>    
      //...         
     <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
         <param-value>com.your_package_path.yourClassFilter</param-value>
     </init-param>
      //...
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://dev.vvirlan.com/jax-rs-use-provider-to-leverage-jax-rs-provider-auto-discovery-feature/) for the more 'classical' approaches (without using the annotation)